# Sub-classing templated class without implementing pure virtual method

Tags: c++, inheritance, templates, pure-virtual

I have the following class definition:

```
template<typename QueueItemT>
class QueueBC
{
protected:
    QueueBC() {}
    virtual ~QueueBC() {}

private:
    virtual IItemBuf* constructItem(const QueueItemT& item) = 0;
}
```

I created the following sub-class:

```
class MyQueue
    : public QueueBC<MyItemT>
{
public:

    MyQueue() {}
    virtual ~MyQueue() {}
};
```

This compiles fine under VS2005, yet I haven't implemented `constructItem()` in the `MyQueue` class.  Any idea why?

Comment: There would be many problems with libraries if you couldn´t compile such code.

Comment: @Tom - definitely!  If I thought about this for a few more seconds before posting, I would have realised what the problem was (I hadn't instantiated the object in my code).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using it:

```
MyQueue m;
```

You can't *instantiate* an abstract class, but you can define one (obviously, as you defined `QueueBC`). `MyQueue` is just as abstract.

For example:

```
struct base // abstract
{
    virtual void one() = 0;
    virtual void two() = 0;
};

struct base_again : base // just as abstract as base
{
};

struct foo : base_again // still abstract
{
    void one() {}
};

struct bar : foo // not abstract
{
    void two() {}
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Pretty obvious now that I think about it, my mind must not have been working very well yesterday :-(

Answer (score 2):

It will compile but you can't create instances.  MyQueue is considered abstract.

Answer (score 2):

Your `MyQueue` subclass is also abstract, just like its base class: therefore, it can't be *instantiated*, but just *defining* it (which is all you've done) is fine!

Answer (score 1):

It would compile fine because the compiler does not know how you intend to use the `MyQueue` class. The way you have defined it, `MyQueue` is also a abstract class. If you try to use it only then you will get a compilation error